# azure iot edge build failing when target architecture is arm32v7 (in ubuntu)

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Im using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-develop-for-linux) example to develop & understand iot edge modules. Im using ubuntu OS. At the end if the target architecture is amd64 when i click on deployment.templete.json and click on build and push iotedge solution its working perfectly. But if change my target architecture to arm32 and do the same getting this error(image). 
[image]

after trying @SatishBoddu-MSFT answer that above issue got resolved. this is the new error(img) during the build.How do i resolve this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check Dockerfile.arm32v7 file and update the image version to as shown below, the pattern can be seen here in this [Doc link](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/dotnetapp/Dockerfile.debian-arm32).

Please try as shown below and let us know if you need further help.

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/**sdk:3.1** AS build-env

OR

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/**sdk:3.1-buster** AS build-env

[image]

Please refer to [Linux arm32 Tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/).

Also see the similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1537#issuecomment-615269150) which gives the more info.

Comment: hi ur solution resolved the issue. but i ran into another issue which i updated in the question. can u pls chk that

Comment: Could you please confirm your host machine architecture, OS ?, Docker Container running Windows or Linux?. I am using Win 10 Pro(x64)-Docker Linux Containers.

Comment: i'm running ubuntu inside VMware on my pc which is having windows 10pro(x64)

Comment: Could you please try on your windows 10pro(x64) pc, with Docker installed with Linux Containers running, as part of troubleshooting.